# How to match words with apostrophe using SQLite FTS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, full-text-search

i'm developing for iOS, currently using FTS4

i have a word with an apostrophe, say: Bob's
i want to make it so even when the user types in Bobs, we get a match.
The apostrophe is currently causing an issue because it causes two separate tokens, Bob and "s".

I"m using tokenize=simple right now
Anybody know of a way to ignore the apostrophe (or any other special character) during the token generation process?

Comment: Yes, there is [a way](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#custom_application_defined_tokenizers).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently when working with a simple English/Gaelic phrase book app. Searching for the English phrase "It's true" was fine, but "Its true" gave no results.

As CL notes in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023102/how-to-match-words-with-apostrophe-using-sqlite-fts#comment67327976_40023102) the clean way is to make your own tokenizer, but that may not be possible if you're relying on an sqlite implementation provided by whatever platform you are targeting.

I went for a hacky solution (not applicable to all scenarios) but I offer it in case it may help someone else.

Simplifying a bit, assume you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary (id int, english varchar(255), english_normalized varchar(255))
```

When you're populating the database, scan the english terms for apostrophes and then append a non-apostrophe addendum to the phrase. For example, "Lisa's dress" would become "Lisa's dress lisas" (but only in the english_normalized column).

Then create a virtual table for FTS:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE dictionary_search USING fts3 (id, english)
```

followed by

```
INSERT INTO dictionary_search SELECT id,english_normalized FROM dictionary
```

Something like this will then get you the original un-mangled phrase:

```
SELECT english FROM dictionary WHERE id IN
(
   SELECT dictionary_search.id 
    FROM dictionary_search
   WHERE 
    dictionary_search.english match '[query]*'
)
```

Replacing [query] with "lisa's" returns "lisa's dress" (as it always did) but searching for "lisas" now also produces "lisa's dress".

Obviously this approach may not be practicable for really big datasets, but I'm using it with a phrasebook of several thousand entries and it works fine.